# Creating user account login page with passport and express session

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express-session, passport-local

Am trying to use passport and express session log in user but I want to allow the user to use either username or email to log in to their account. How can I achieve this with nodejs and mongoose and get the current login user
This what i have tried with my login page

router.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local", async (req, res, next) => {
const { usernameOrEmail, password } = req.body

```
if (!usernameOrEmail) {
  var err = new Error("username is required!");
  err.status = 403;
  next(err);
} else if (!password) {
  var err = new Error("Please provide password!");
  err.status = 403;
  next(err);
}

else {
  try {
    //Login code

    //$query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username ='$username' ";
    let canProceed = false;
    let userId;
    if (isValidEmail(usernameOrEmail)) {
      let emailObject = await Email.findOne({
        value: usernameOrEmail,
        subjectType: 0,
        status: 1,
      });
      if (!!emailObject) {
        canProceed = true;
        userId = emailObject.subjectId;
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "This email doesn't exist in our records",
        });
      }
    } else if (isValidUsername(usernameOrEmail)) {
      let usernameObject = await Username.findOne({
        value: usernameOrEmail,
        subjectType: 0,
        status: 1,
      });
      if (!!usernameObject) {
        canProceed = true;
        userId = usernameObject.subjectId;
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "This username doesn't exist in our records",
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Please provide either a username or email",
      });
    }
    if (canProceed && !!userId) {
      let passwordObject = await Password.findOne({
        subjectType: 0,
        status: 1,
        subjectId: userId,
      });
      if (!!(await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordObject.value))) {
        if (userObject.status == 1) {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          res.json({
            token: token,
            success: true,
            status: "Login successful Successful!",
          });
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried share your code

Comment: This is my login page

Comment: what is your login page?

Comment: You need to write a custom local strategy that searches the users collection for the value in the username/email field by email. If that returns nothing search by the username field, if that returns nothing return incorrect username/password. In either case if the user is found, check the password is correct and if so return done. For an example of a custom local strategy see the docs:
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Comment: have update the question and add my login page with it